Specify bevel on attributes 4.3
Testing rn this new attribute bevel feature in 4.3. And wanted to know, if maybe someone could figure this out. So I'd like  add support loops with bevel modidfier to edges and then add regular .5 shape bevel to exact same edge, but instead it bevels only border edges. Tried using some float and color types for attribute(color one works for all 3 loops btw, not only bordering), but still result is not what I'd like. Maybe there's some way to shrink attribute selection by edges via geonodes? I don't know, never tried them, so hope you may know




I don't think it's possible in any elegant way. I think you could duplicate the edges then create the new attribute based on their location because they will match the ones support bevel creates... Or you could grow and shrink the attribute... but that only works in some cases... I think for this to work we should wait for bevel implementation inside Geometry nodes.

Why do you need support loops if you are making another bevel anyway? Support loops are needed for subdivision surface modifier... Or to fix normals in a backwards way... You can fix normals with weighted normals modifier instead of support loops... Or is there another reason?

Such way of beveling with 0.5 profile bevel on top of support loops is just one of the ways to make bevels with, I’d say interesting continuity. So at least for such purpose. And realizing how to work with those bevels on attributes may open some new ways for creativity in terms of nondestructive modeling

Yes, but why? Why have support loops for a bevel?

Compare how profile looks like on subdivided support loops, on a regular .5 bevel and on the 75% .5 bevel weith support loops. (Try with such a setup https://prnt.sc/uTgb0ybOtLX4)

Hopefully this answer attracts attention of someone who actually knows what they are doing with geometry nodes and they provide a better answer, but one messy ugly way would be to save the edges(actual geometry) with one Geometry Nodes modifier so you can use them to create an attribute for the new edges created by support loop bevel that overlap the original ones:

 (4.3.0 Release Candidate!)

Thanks, even though it would be better to have a bevel node (it has got to happen eventually) I understand the question better and can see how the feature could be used creatively now.

Here is how I understand your question, which has three distinct parts.
a)How do storing attributes and Bevel Edge Weight work in 4.3?
b)How can I alter an edge or loopcut already created by the bevel modifier?
c)Can geo nodes control where the bevel weight is applied?
a)How do storing attributes and Bevel Edge Weight work in 4.3?
Now you can use any attribute.  Here is the traditional way:

Add the bevel modifier to an object.
Select an object,  Enter into Edit mode, select edges
Go to the Edges drop-down menu and select Bevel Edge Weight
Adjust the value on the range slider to assign a value, the selected edges will turn blue, and the Bevel_Edge_Weight attribute will be added to the list.
Change the limit method of the bevel to 'weight' and select 'Edge Bevel Weight' and all edges with values greater than 0 will be considered.

b)How can I alter an edge or loopcut already created by the bevel modifier?
By stacking modifiers- or applying it.
c)Can geo nodes control where the bevel weight is applied?
Yes, because now any attribute can be used.
In geo nodes, you do this by using the Store Named Attribute node.
For example, you could define a selection by Z-position rather than specific edges and store this as an attribute to be used by the Bevel Modifier.
This would help you select programmatically instead of manually selecting the edges.




These are two simple node trees used as examples to store attributes which will be passed on to two separate bevels.   (select by normal, and choose by position)
There are many creative ways to use this feature in 4.3.


I don't want it to be limited by vertex groups, I need it to be limited by attributes applied on edges. Limiting it on vertex groups will cause many limitation, for example appling it to 3/4 edges of a quad via vertex groups will make bevel work on all 4 edges.

I don't think you understood the question. Weight in 4.3 now lets you choose the attribute the weight is stored in. He wants to use this to have 2 different bevels but the issue is - how do you create the weight for the second bevel modifier if you want it to be on the edges that the first one creates. I guess this would also apply if done with vertex groups - how do you create a group for the middle edge loop and use it for a bevel modifier if it has to bevel middle edge loop created by previous bevel modifier?

@common_goldfish Trickier indeed. I cannot think of anything. The new bevel makes side edges inherit the attribute, but not the ones inside the bevel... It would need to be quite an elaborate mess with multiple geometry nodes modifiers and duplicated geometry as far as I understand... Maybe some geometry nodes wizards know something I don't though...

I see how passing the attribute is possible using the tree described here, but I would like more information about how what this new trick can do.

didn't try this updated version yet, but still think it's quite not what I need bcs of vertex groups. As I've said earlier, vertex groups bring limitations in cases when you want to bevel 3 out of 4 edges of a quad
